# Basic question about convergence of top and penultimate eigenvalues of a sequence of operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, spectral-radius

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}$ $\newcommand{\ab}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}$ $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbf C}$

## Questions

Let $I$ be the unit interval.
Let $H=L^2(I)$ and $T:H\to H$ be a compact self-adjoint operator.
Let $f_n:I\to I$ be a sequence of function in $L^\infty(I)$ such that $f_n\to \mathbf 1$ in $L^\infty$  where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the function $I\to \C$ which takes the value $1$ everywhere.
Define $T_n=f_n T$, that is $T_n:H\to H$ takes $\xi$ to $(T\xi)f _n$, that is, the pointwise product of $T\xi$ and $f_n$.

> **Question 1.**
> I am trying to see if
> $$
> \lambda_{\text{max}}(T_n) \to \lambda_{\text{max}}(T)
> $$
> where $\lambda_\text{max}(T_n)$ denotes the largest eigenvalue of $T_n$ and similarly for $T$.

(We know that since each $T_n$ is compact and has real spectra as argued in the Appendix).

*Progress on the Question 1.* If $\rho$ denotes the spectral radius, then by the spectral radius formula, we have
$$
\rho(T_n) = \limsup_{k\to \infty} \norm{(T_n)^k}^{1/k} = \limsup_{k\to \infty} \norm{(f_n T)^k}^{1/k}
$$
If $n$ is large enough then we have $\norm{f_n-\mathbf 1}\leq \varepsilon$, which given from above that
$$
\rho(T_n) \leq \lim\sup_{k\to \infty} \norm{f_n^k T^k}^{1/k}\leq (1+\varepsilon)\limsup_{k\to \infty} \norm{T^k}^{1/k} = (1+\varepsilon) \rho(T)
$$
Similarly we can show that for large enough $n$ we have
$$
(1-\varepsilon)\rho(T) \leq \rho(T_n)
$$
giving that $\rho(T_n)\to \rho(T)$ as $n\to \infty$.
Since the spectrum may have negative values, this does not necessarily give $\lambda_{\text{max}}(T_n)\to \lambda_{\text{max}}(T)$ but is a step in that direction.

Also, if $\lambda_{\text{penmax}}(T)$ denotes the second to largest eigenvalue of $T$, then,

> **Question 2.**
> Is it also true that
> $$
> \lambda_{\text{penmax}}(T_n) \to \lambda_{\text{penmax}}(T)
> $$
> as $n\to \infty$.

If there is something more general known about convergence of spectra (of compact operators or otherwise) then please feel free to share.

## Appendix

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be a small positive number and $f:I\to I$ be such that $\norm{f-\mathbf 1}_\infty<\varepsilon$, where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the constant function $1$.
Let $H=L^2(I)$.
Let $T:H\to H$ be a compact operator and  define $fT: H\to H$ as $(fT)\xi = f\ T\xi$ for all $\xi\in H$.

> We will show that if $T$ is a compact self-adjoint operator then $fT$ is compact with all its eigenvalues real.

If $T$ is compact then there is a sequence $(T_n)$ of bounded linear operators on $H$ such that each $T_n$ has finite rank and $T_n\to T$ in operator norm.
Clearly, $fT_n\to fT$ in operator norm.
Since each $fT_n$ is also of finite rank, we see that $fT$ is indeed compact.

For any $g\in L^\infty(I)$ close to $\mathbf 1$ in the $L^\infty$ norm, define an inner product $\ab{\cdot, \cdot}_g$ on $L^2(I)$ as $\ab{\xi, \zeta}_g = \int_I \xi\bar \zeta g\ d\mu$.
It is easy to check that this is indeed an inner product.
Let us write $H_g$ to denote $L^2(I)$ equipped with the inner product $\ab{\cdot, \cdot}_f$.
Then we have
$$
\ab{(fT)\xi, \zeta}_{1/f} = \ab{f\ T\xi, \zeta}_{1/f} = \ab{T\xi, \zeta} = \ab{\xi, T \zeta} = \ab{\xi, f\ T\zeta}_{1/f} = \ab{\xi, (fT) \zeta}_{1/f}
$$
This shows that $fT$ is self-adjoint with respect to the inner product $\ab{\cdot, \cdot}_{1/f}$.

Cross Posted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810179/basic-question-about-convergence-of-top-and-penultimate-eigenvalues-of-a-sequenc).

Comment: The variational formulas for eigenvalues should imply that, for any $k$, the $k$-th largest eigenvalue of $T_n$ converges to the $k$-largest eigenvalue of $T$, and similarly for the smallest, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem

Comment: More generally, for self-adjoint operators (not necessarily compact), the spectrum behaves very-well with respect to perturbations: if $S,T$ are self-adjoint operators with $\|S - T \|\leq \varepsilon$, then the spectrum of $T$ is contained in the $\varepsilon$-neighborhoud of the spectrum of $S$. This applies here, as (say if $\|f_n -1\| \leq 1/2$) $f_n T = \sqrt{f_n} (\sqrt{f_n} T \sqrt{f_n}) \sqrt{f_n}^{-1}$ is similar to $\sqrt{f_n} T \sqrt{f_n}$, and $\|\sqrt{f_n} T \sqrt{f_n} - T\|\leq 10 \|T\| \|f_n-1\|$.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle Thank you for the comment. Can you please give me a reference for the statement that you made about perturbations (that if $S$ and $T$ are self-adjoint with $\|S-T\|<\varepsilon$ then the spectra of $S$ and $T$ are within $\varepsilon$ neighborhoods of each other). Thank you.

Comment: I am bad at references, but I would be surprised it this did not belong to standard textbooks on spectral theory for self-adjoint operators. Here is a short proof. By symmetry and translation, we have to justify that if the spectrum of $S$ does not intersect $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$, then $T$ is invertible. But in that case $\|S^{-1}\| < 1/\varepsilon$ (the norm of a self-adjoint operator is its spectral radius), so $S^{-1}(S-T)$ has norm $<1$, so $T = S( 1 - S^{-1}(S-T))$ is invertible as a composition of two invertible operators.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle Thank you. That helps a lot.